# Obter variável nullable DateTime serializada nas respostas do serviço WCF

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-service, wcf

Eu tenho um serviço WCF com uma variável *nullable* ***DateTime*** em um DataContract como mostrado abaixo. Por causa de regras de negócios este DataMember não pode ter o  **EmitDefaultValue** setado para *true* e o tipo tem que ser ***"DateTime?"***

```
[DataContract (Name = "DADOS")]
classe public Dados
{
    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
}
```

Meu ***DataContract*** está especificado como abaixo, vejam que eu tenho que ter duas versões do método ***WebInvoke*** para manter a interoperabilidade entre sistemas diferentes (respostas no formato JSON e XML):

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestService
    {
        [OperationContract (Name = "ConsultaDadosXml")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/xml?token={token}")]
        Dados ConsultaDadosXml (token string);

        [OperationContract (Name = "ConsultaDadosJson")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/json?token={token}")]
        Dados ConsultaDadosJson (token string);
    }
```

O problema é que quando **DtNascimento** vem corretamente preenchida com um bom valor válido do banco de dados, tudo funciona bem, quando ela vem com um valor nulo do banco de dados, a resposta XML / JSON vem sem a tag NASCIMENTO, ok, isso está acontecendo porque **EmitDefaultValue** **= false**. Eu posso definir, através de *procedures* que meu banco de dados me envie um valor vazio, só que quando faço isso o objeto serializado vem com um valor MinDate nas respostas.

Versão xml:

```
     <DADOS>
         <NASCIMENTO> 1900-01-01T00: 00: 00 </ NASCIMENTO>
     </ DADOS>
```

Json versão:

```
{
    "NASCIMENTO": "/ Date (-2208981600000-0200) /",
}
```

O que eu realmente preciso é uma variável(tag) vazia sendo mostrada nas respostas quando este valor for nulo, isso porque há outros sistemas conectados no serviço web tentando interpretar esses valores, de modo a melhor solução seria manter essas variáveis ​​vazias da seguinte forma:

Xml:

```
<DADOS>
<NASCIMENTO> </ NASCIMENTO>
</ DADOS>
```

Json:

```
{
    "NASCIMENTO": "",
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com alguma sugestão?

Comment: o que acontece quando você coloca o `IsRequired = true` junto do `EmitDefaultValue = false` e envia um null? acredito que seja o que você procura.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade, Eu passei a receber uma System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException. Acho que justamente por eu estar recebendo um valor nulo do BD e marcando ele como Required no meu contrato. Quando o BD responde com um valor não nulo, a exception não ocorre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira ideia para resolver este problema seria usar uma propriedade extra, do tipo `string`, decorada com o `[DataMember]` como no código abaixo:

```
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS", Namespace = "")]
public class Dados
{
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    private string WireDtNascimento
    {
        set { /* nao usado */ }
        get
        {
            return this.DtNascimento == null ?
                "" :
                DtNascimento.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que como você precisa usar o mesmo tipo em duas formas de serialização diferentes, e o formato do `DateTime` em XML (o que eu usei no exemplo acima) é diferente do formato em JSON (`\/Date(...)\/)`.

Há duas soluções para resolver esse problema: você pode olhar no call stack pra ver se o serializer que está sendo usado é JSON, e usar essa informação para decidir como vai converter o valor. Funciona, mas é um *hack* bem grande (você está baseando a sua lógica de acordo com um detalhe de implementação do WCF) que eu não aconselharia...

```
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS", Namespace = "")]
public class Dados
{
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    private string WireDtNascimento
    {
        set { /* nao usado */ }
        get
        {
            if (this.DtNascimento == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                var usandoJson = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Any(st => st.GetMethod().DeclaringType == typeof(DataContractJsonSerializer));
                if (usandoJson)
                {
                    var millis = (long)this.DtNascimento.Value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
                    var offset = this.DtNascimento.Value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ? "" : this.DtNascimento.Value.ToString("%K").Replace(":", "");
                    return "/Date(" + millis + offset + ")/";
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.DtNascimento.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uma outra alternativa - já que você está usando dois métodos, pode usar um `DataContract` para cada formato de resposta. Haverá um pouco mais de duplicação do código, mas você ganha em legibilidade.

```
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS", Namespace = "")]
public class DadosJson
{
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    private string WireDtNascimento
    {
        set { /* nao usado */ }
        get
        {
            if (this.DtNascimento == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                var millis = (long)this.DtNascimento.Value.ToUniversalTime()
                    .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
                    .TotalMilliseconds;
                var offset = this.DtNascimento.Value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ?
                    "" :
                    this.DtNascimento.Value.ToString("%K").Replace(":", "");
                return "/Date(" + millis + offset + ")/";
            }
        }
    }
}
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS", Namespace = "")]
public class DadosXml
{
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    private string WireDtNascimento
    {
        set { /* nao usado */ }
        get
        {
            return this.DtNascimento == null ?
                "" :
                this.DtNascimento.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "ConsultaDadosXml")]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/xml?token={token}")]
    DadosXml ConsultaDadosXml(string token);

    [OperationContract(Name = "ConsultaDadosJson")]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/json?token={token}")]
    DadosJson ConsultaDadosJson(string token);
}
public class Service : IRestService
{
    public DadosXml ConsultaDadosXml(string token)
    {
        var result = new DadosXml();
        if (!"NULL".Equals(token, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result.DtNascimento = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public DadosJson ConsultaDadosJson(string token)
    {
        return new DadosJson
        {
            DtNascimento =  ConsultaDadosXml(token).DtNascimento
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Realment eu já pensei na solução que você apresenta com boa legibilidade, o problema é que o sistema é grande e existe clientes já utilizando o serviço, não posso mudar o contrato. (retorno de Dados => DadosXml/DadosJson). A Solução hack apresentada, geraria algum tipo de vulnerabilidade no serviço? Eu tinha pensado em algo parecido, mas não em obter a informação do StackTrace e sim da URI pois no WebInvoke eu declaro: UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/json?token={token}"

Comment: Boa ideia, se no momento de criar a classe `Dados` você passar o tipo de serialização isso pode funcionar. Essa solução (usar uma outra propriedade na serialização) não vai gerar nenhuma vulnerabilidade, eu diria que isso é a solução recomendada para esse cenário.